# How to SELECT all rows in a query where specific rows meet a certain criteria?

Tags: sql

I have a query that accesses data from three tables:

```
SELECT fg.factGroupName, mc.CI, mt.Config
                    FROM MetricTypes mt
                    INNER JOIN MetricCollection mc ON mt.TypeId = mc.MetricType
                    INNER JOIN factGroup fg ON fg.factGroupId = mc.Factgroup
                    WHERE mt.ToolName = 2 AND mt.TypeName = 'inputs' AND mt.Deploy = 'Y' AND mc.Deploy = 'Y';
```

The tables look like this:

```
factGroup                     
|-------------|--------------|
|factGroupId  |factGroupName |
|-------------|--------------|
|      20     | test_servers |
|      21     | prod_servers |
|-------------|--------------|

MetricTypes
|-------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-----------|
|TypeId       |TypeName      |ToolName      |Config      |Deploy     |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-----------|
|     10      |  inputs      |     2        | foo        |   Y       |
|     11      |  inputs      |     2        | bar        |           |
|     12      |  outputs     |     4        | giggle     |           |
|     13      |  inbetween   |     6        | biz        |           |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-----------|

MetricCollection
|-------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-----------|
|MetricId     |Factgroup     |MetricType    |CI          |Deploy     |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-----------|
|    1        |     20       |     10       |  alpha     |   Y       |
|    2        |     20       |     11       |  beta      |           |
|    3        |     20       |     12       |  gamma     |           |
|    4        |     21       |     13       |  theta     |           |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|------------|-----------|
```

The output from the query looks like this:

```
|-------------|--------------|--------------|
|factGroupName|       CI     |   Config     |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|
| test_servers|  alpha       |    foo       |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|
```

How would I adjust my query in order to get a result which reflects all `CI` and `Config` fields for a given `factGroupName`, and not just the ones that have the `Y` flag in the `Deploy` fields? In other words, I'd like to have my output look like this:

```
|-------------|--------------|--------------|
|factGroupName|       CI     |   Config     |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|
| test_servers|  alpha       |    foo       |
| test_servers|  beta        |    bar       |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|
```

To clarify: I want to keep the condition in place to check for the existence of a "Y" flag in the two Deploy fields, as the script associated with this query uses that flag as a trigger to perform additional work.

Comment: What if you just removed the conditions on the `deploy` field?

Comment: The script that this query lives within uses the "Y" flag as a trigger to perform additional work. If the "Y" doesn't exist, the script goes to sleep until its next scheduled iteration.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you want results for all values of `Deploy`, then you can't filter the "Y" records out in your `WHERE` clause.  If your script needs to know the value of `Deploy`, then include it in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I've added additional data into the three tables in my example to better reflect what the tables look like. Now, you'll note that there is an assortment of data in the `TypeName`, `ToolName`, and `factGroupName` fields. I'm only interested in any rows that have a "Y" in the two `Deploy` fields, which indicates that they have been recently updated and are ready to be pushed out to a file. In order for the file to be complete, though, I need to collect all of the other rows that belong to the same `factGroupName` as the rows with the "Y" flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INNER JOIN` on `Deploy = 'Y'` appears to be the problem.

**Table example:**

```
create table #factgroup
(
factgroupid int,
factgroupname varchar(20)
)

create table #metrictypes
(
typeid int,
typename varchar(10),
toolname int,
config varchar(10),
deploy varchar(1)
)

create table #metriccollection
(
metricid int,
factgroup int,
metrictype int,
ci varchar(10),
deploy varchar(1)
)

insert into #factgroup values (20, 'test_servers')
insert into #metrictypes values (10, 'inputs', 2, 'foo', 'Y')
insert into #metrictypes (typeid, typename, toolname, config) values (11, 'inputs', 2, 'bar')
insert into #metriccollection values (1, 20, 10, 'alpha', 'Y')
insert into #metriccollection (metricid, factgroup, metrictype, ci) values (2, 20, 11, 'beta')
```

**Try this (with hashtags removed):**

```
SELECT fg.factGroupName, mc.CI, mt.Config

FROM #MetricTypes mt
INNER JOIN #MetricCollection mc ON mt.TypeId = mc.MetricType
INNER JOIN #factGroup fg ON fg.factGroupId = mc.Factgroup

WHERE mt.ToolName = 2 AND mt.TypeName = 'inputs'

and mt.toolname in (
                      select distinct mt.ToolName
                      from #metrictypes mt
                      where mt.deploy = 'y'
                   )

and mc.factgroup in (
                      select distinct mc.factgroup
                      from #metriccollection mc
                      where mc.deploy = 'y'
                    )
```